Initializing very large matrices
I have a question concerning very large matrices. In my specific case my matrix has the dimensions $2\cdot 128^3\times 2\cdot 128^3$. I am aware of the fact that the main problem by dealing with such matrices is the limited space for saving such an object. However, most of the elements in my matrix are zero. More specific, my matrix looks like
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
-b & -a 
\end{pmatrix}\,\, .$$
Here $b$ is a diagonal matrix and $a$ has non-zero elements on the diagonal and on the off-diaogonals (and in the bottom left corner and in the top right corner). My code to initialize the matrix looks like this:
M = 10;
r = ConstantArray[0, {M, M}];
Do[If[j == 1, r[[1]][[1]] = 1; r[[1]][[M]] = -1]; 
  If[1 < j < M, r[[j]][[j - 1]] = -1; r[[j]][[j]] = 1]; 
  If[j == M, r[[j]][[j]] = 1; r[[j]][[j - 1]] = -1], {j, 1, M}];
k = ConstantArray[0, {M, M}];
Do[If[j == 1, k[[1]][[1]] = -1; k[[1]][[2]] = 1]; 
  If[1 < j < M, k[[j]][[j]] = -1; k[[j]][[j + 1]] = 1]; 
  If[j == M, k[[j]][[j]] = -1; k[[j]][[1]] = 1], {j, 1, M}];
b = Table[Table[If[i == j, i, 0], {i, 1, M}], {j, 1, M}]
a = (k - r);
A = ArrayFlatten[{{a, b}, {-b, -a}}];

I know (or better I guess) that my style of initializing the matrix is very inefficient. I am therefore glad for any advice. For small $M$ all is fine, but not for very large $M$. My general goal is to calculate eigenvalues of the resulting matrix.
Thanks For help!

Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! Have you thought about using SparseArray? It is more memory efficient for matrices with low density of non-zero elements, and it also has a various ways of initialization.

As Domen pointed out, SparseArray is the right data structure. It also has convenient constructors for banded matrices.
a = SparseArray[
     {
      Band[{1, 1}] -> -2, Band[{2, 1}] -> 1, Band[{1, 2}] -> 1, {M, 1} -> 1, {1, M} -> 1
     }, 
     {M, M}];
b = SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> Range[1, M]}, {M, M}]
A = ArrayFlatten[{{a, b}, {-b, -a}}];

